# Customize hover text for plotly heatmap

Tags: r, hover, heatmap, plotly

I have a `matrix` (gene expression from several conditions):

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(50*10),nrow=50,ncol=10,dimnames=list(paste("C",1:50,sep="."),paste("G",1:10,sep=".")))
```

Which I want to plot as a `heatmap` using `plotly` in `R`.

```
require(plotly)
heatmap.plotly <- plot_ly(x=colnames(mat),y=rownames(mat),z=mat,type="heatmap",colors=colorRamp(c("darkblue","white","darkred")),colorbar=list(title="Score",len=0.4)) %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title="Condition"),xaxis=list(title="Gene"))
```

works fine.

However, I'd like to add text that would be seen only when hovered over.

I thought this would work:

```
conditions.text <- paste(paste("C",1:50,sep="."),rep(paste(LETTERS[sample(26,10,replace=T)],collapse=""),50),sep=":")
heatmap.plotly <- plot_ly(x=colnames(mat),y=rownames(mat),z=mat,type="heatmap",colors=colorRamp(c("darkblue","white","darkred")),colorbar=list(title="Score",len=0.4),hoverinfo='text',text=~conditions.text) %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title="Condition"),xaxis=list(title="Gene"))
```

But it doesn't. I actually don't see any text when hovering over the plot.

Note that I'm working with a `matrix` rather than a `melted` `data.frame`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing an array of 50x10 into your heatmap but a list of 50 entries as hoverinfo. Both the input for the heatmap and the text must have the same dimensions.

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(50*10),nrow=50,ncol=10,dimnames=list(paste("C",1:50,sep="."),paste("G",1:10,sep=".")))

conditions.text <- paste(paste("C",1:50,sep="."),rep(paste(LETTERS[sample(26,10,replace=T)],collapse=""),500),sep=":")
conditions.text <- matrix(unlist(conditions.text), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)

plot_ly(z=mat,
        type="heatmap",
        hoverinfo='text',
        text=conditions.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

So the `~` syntax in plotly is designed to work as a reference to the `data = ...` object, like `data$...`. Since plotly's heat map doesn't work with the `data` argument, it won't work here. You will need to construct a matrix with the same dimensions as `mat` for supplying to the `text = ...` argument. A little clunky but it makes for nice plots:

```
# make a matrix same dimensions as mat
text.mat <- matrix(conditions.text, nrow(mat), ncol(mat))
heatmap.plotly <- plot_ly(x=colnames(mat),y=rownames(mat),z=mat,
                          type="heatmap",colors=colorRamp(c("darkblue","white","darkred")),
                          colorbar=list(title="Score",len=0.4), hoverinfo='text', text=text.mat) %>%
    layout(yaxis=list(title="Condition"),xaxis=list(title="Gene"))
heatmap.plotly
```

If you want to build a multiline hoverinfo for text, just use inline `<\br>` tags in `text.mat` and plotly will read them as html and create the line returns when rendered.